# Facebook graph API - OAuth Token

Tags: php, facebook, token

I'm trying to retrieve data using the new graph API, however the token I'm retriving from OAuth doesn't appear to be working.

The call I'm making is as follows;

```
$token = file_get_contents('https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?type=client_cred&client_id=<app_id>&client_secret=<app secret>');
```

This returns a token with a string length of 41. To give you an example of what is returned I have provided below a sample (converted all numbers to 0, all capital letters to 'A' and small case letters to 'a'

```
access_token=000000000000|AaaAaaAaaAAaAaaaaAaaAa0aaAA.
```

I take this access token and attach it to the call request for data, it doesn't appear to be the correct token as it returns nothing. I make the data call as follows;

```
file_get_contents('https://graph.facebook.com/<my_page's_id>/statuses?access_token=000000000000|AaaAaaAaaAAaAaaaaAaaAa0aaAA.')
```

When I manually retrieve this page directly through the browser I get an 500/Internal Server Error Message.

Any assistance would be grately appreciated.

---

Update:

I've since changed the method from file_get_contents() to curl. By retreiving the headers I get the following error message ...

```
{"error":{"type":"OAuthException","message":"Missing client_id"}}
```

but my post array includes 'client_id'?!

Comment: hi did you still have the same problem

Answer (score 24, accepted):

> Don't use type=client_cred, this is
>   not the access token that a user
>   grants for your app to use. You don't
>   need redirect_uri or code or any
>   approval to get the client_cred type
>   access token.
>
> Facebook implements an early draft of
>   OAuth 2 at this time. So there is not
>   support for "state" yet.
>
> But it is nice that you can suffix
>   your state to the redirect_uri, the
>   important point to note here is that
>   the site url that you specified (which
>   is the redirect_uri)

should not have a

> question mark at the end or anywhere
>   in what you suffix as client state,
>   encoded or not. If you did, you will
>   get the dreaded "Error validating
>   verification code"

Don't use like that

http://www.Redirect.com?

Correct Url is http://www.Redirect.com/

Hope it helps.

Comment: This is the right answer. Your redirect_uri has to end with a /. Thanks for telling us!

Comment: Absolutely accurate 100%. Also, as comment: DO NOT USE redirect_uri in $params array given to getLoginUrl() method on the PHP SDK!!! You're gonna break it.

Comment: Daahh! Missing the slash too. Dang!

Answer (score 16):

This works for me :-)

```
header('Location: https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?' . http_build_query(array(
    'client_id'     => FB_APP_ID,
    'type'          => 'client_cred',
    'client_secret' => FB_SECRET,
    'code'          => $code)));
```

Of course you would use file_get_contents instead and parse the token out of the response

Comment: +1 the type=client_cred worked for me.  The page does not redirect to my redirect_uri though.

Comment: type=client_cred seems to issue you a token without a user session (as described in "Authenticating as an Application"). It essentially behaves as if you never passed the code at all. A token without a user session mostly works, but some APIs that need to know who the current user is don't work, most notably: http://graph.facebook.com/me. I've been completely unable to get a token with a user session following the instructions here or at facebook. Kind of frustrating.

Comment: Turns out that facebook's oauth implementation has some quirky bugs related to the content of the redirect_uri parameter. If your redirect uri contains certain chars (e.g. a correctly url encoded colon), it will choke.

Comment: Confirming Brian's comment -- if I have any querystring parameters on my redirect_uri, Facebook chokes when I go to get the token; without the parameters it works fine.  I am correctly urlencoding before setting the redirect_uri parameter.  It's possible Facebook is urldecoding the whole thing more than once, so the parameters on the redirect_uri appear to be part of the main querystring.

Answer (score 8):

I ran into the exact same problem but it turned out the issue is not the encoding of the redirect_uri parameter, or that I had a trailing slash or question mark it's simply that I passed in two different redirect urls (had not read the specification at that time).

The redirect_uri is only used as a redirect once (the first time) to redirect back to the relying party with the "code" token. The 2nd time, the redirect_uri is passed back to the auth server but this time it's not used as you'd expect (to redirect) rather it's used by the authentication server to verify the code. The server responds with the access_token.

https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-oauth-v2-05#section-3.5.2

You'll notice facebook documentation (which is terrible) says **fetch** "Exchange it for an access token by **fetching** https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token. "

In summary, I didn't have to encode or do anything special to the Uri, just pass in the same redirect_uri twice, and **fetch** the 2nd page to get the access_token inside.

Answer (score 6):

You can request an access token via terminal (OSX Users) using curl:

```
curl -F type=client_cred -F client_id=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx -F client_secret=c0f88xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx1b949d1b8 https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token
```

Once you have your access token you can then use it in future curl requests to makes changes via the new graph API:

Post a message to a profile id:

```
curl -F 'access_token=xxxxxxxxxxxxx|mGVx50lxxxxxxxxxxxxhzC2w.'  -F 'message=Hello Likers'  -F 'id=1250000000000905'  https ://graph.facebook.com/feed
```

Comment: won't the access token expires in a few days?

Comment: Hi Volcanic, I'm trying to use this technique to post to a feed for liked webpage, should that work, any ideas? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10419371/how-to-programmatically-publish-to-a-facebook-feed-for-a-liked-webpage

Answer (score 3):

Please note that

'type'          => 'client_cred',

is only a way to circumvent the below, having said that, the above also works

After the user authorizes your application, we redirect the user back to the redirect URI you specified with a verification string in the argument code, which can be exchanged for an oauth access token. Exchange it for an access token by fetching https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token. Pass the **exact** same redirect_uri as in the previous step:

via: by: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/api
see also: http://forum.developers.facebook.net/viewtopic.php?pid=238371

Comment: thanks!  the *exact* same redirect_uri was what helped me.  :)

Answer (score 2):

Try to follow the API, i.e without `type` but add `redirect_uri` and `code` (even though we don't need it):

```
$token = file_get_contents('https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=<app_id>&client_secret=<app secret>&redirect_uri=<url>&code=<code>');
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe your problem is solved but i yet not found accepted answer from you and maybe this answer helps those who face similar problem

First we have to Create our Application instance.

```
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
  'appId' => '149865361795547',
  'secret' => 'ee827a8df6202e1857b3fc28f3185a61',
  'cookie' => true,
));
```

easy way to get **access_token**

```
$token = $facebook->getAccessToken();
```

get page status as you ask in your question

```
$response = $facebook->api($pageID . '/feed','get',$token);
```

***thanks..***

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have url encoded your query parameters, your one should actually be:

```
000000000000%7CAaaAaaAaaAAaAaaaaAaaAa0aaAA
```

Note: also the type parameter seems to be required, without it you also get 500 error with message:

```
{
   "error": {
   "type": "OAuthException",
   "message": "Error validating verification code."
   }
}
```

rather than the message you get with other missing parameters. Cannot see that mentioned in [the documentation](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/).

Comment: at what point is the type parameter required. it's included in the $token = file_get_contents(...)

Comment: Oh, sorry that's a note to self -- you already have that in your access token part

Comment: Hi, i get the following error:  {
   "error": {
      "type": "OAuthException",
      "message": "Missing redirect_uri parameter."
   }
} What could be the problem with the redirect url ? I hope everything i gave is correct.

Answer (score 0):

You can also get this error if your connect URL isn't a base of your redirect URI. For example

```
Connect URL: http://www.example.com/fb/connect/

Redirect URI: http://www.example.com/fb/connect/redirect
```

I ran into an issue where my redirect URI was the same as the connect URL, but I forgot the trailing / on the redirect URI so FB saw them as different and failed the auth.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for posting in old question. 
Due to changes in recent fb access. 
I have this code working and thought I would post for anyone else requiring help.
This method works great with jQuery ajax and eliminates the redirect_uri given example from facebook.

```
$ch = curl_init("https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=INSERT_YOUR_APP_ID_HERE&client_secret=INSERT_YOUR_APP_SECRET_HERE&grant_type=client_credentials");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOSIGNAL, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT_MS, 30000);
$data = curl_exec($ch);
$curl_errno = curl_errno($ch);
$curl_error = curl_error($ch);
curl_close($ch);

if ($curl_errno > 0) 
{
        echo "cURL Error ($curl_errno): $curl_error\n";
} 
else 
{
    echo $data;
}
```

outputs a public available access_token for showing to non facebook users. i.e a facebook page feed wall via graph api for websites.
access_token=191648007534048|eVilnMh585rlQLZLvBAmqM6s-1g

[php](/questions/tagged/php)[facebook](/questions/tagged/facebook)[oauth2](/questions/tagged/oauth2)[facebook-accesstoken](/questions/tagged/facebook-accesstoken)[facebook-oauth](/questions/tagged/facebook-oauth)

Answer (score -6):

you need to enter an actual values instead of the < app_id > and a secret value.
the code is a unique value that you need to generate , and the redirect URL that you provide will then verify that the code is correct.

Comment: dear he is actually maybe don't want to show his app id here thats why he wrote <app_id>