# Problems with OAuth 2 Gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, facebook, oauth

I have a rails project using https://github.com/intridea/oauth2.  In my rails app I have the following code:

**ApplicationController.rb**

```
def facebook_client
  OAuth2::Client.new(FacebookOauthCredentials::APP_ID, FacebookOauthCredentials::APP_SECRET, :site => 'https://graph.facebook.com')
end
```

**FacebookController.rb**

```
def facebook_session_create(poster, featured_item)
  redirect_to facebook_client.web_server.authorize_url(:scope => 'publish_stream', :redirect_uri => "http://localhost:3000/facebook/facebook_callback")
end

def facebook_callback

  if(params[:code])
    begin
      access_token = facebook_client.web_server.get_access_token(params[:code], :redirect_uri => "http://localhost:3000/facebook/facebook_callback")

      access_token.post('/me/feed', "testing #{rand(1000)}")
    rescue OAuth2::HTTPError => e
      render :text => e.response.body
    end
  end
end
```

Every time I run this code I get this response:

```
{"error":{"type":"OAuthException","message":"Error validating verification code."}}
```

However, I use the sinatra app supplied in the OAuth2 gem's readme file, it works fine.

```
def client
  OAuth2::Client.new(FacebookOauthCredentials::APP_ID, FacebookOauthCredentials::APP_SECRET, :site => 'https://graph.facebook.com')
end

get '/auth/facebook' do
   redirect client.web_server.authorize_url(
    :redirect_uri => redirect_uri,
    :scope => 'publish_stream'
  )
end

get '/auth/facebook/callback' do
  access_token = client.web_server.get_access_token(params[:code], :redirect_uri =>   redirect_uri)

  begin
    user = JSON.parse(access_token.post('/me/feed', :message => "testing # {rand(10000)}"))
  rescue Exception => e
    return e.response.body
  end

  user.inspect
end

def redirect_uri
  uri = URI.parse(request.url)
  uri.path = '/auth/facebook/callback'
  uri.query = nil
  uri.to_s
end
```

I have tried reproducing the steps using irb, but I an http 400 error.  I'm not sure if it's for the same reason as the rails app, or if it's because I'm doing a hybrid of console and web browser operation.  Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you good configure your facebook application with a valid callback url and you use this callback url ?

Comment: The callback url configured in facebook is http://localhost, and the callback domain is configured as localhost.

Answer (score 2):

I found the answer to my problem on this page [Facebook graph API - OAuth Token](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2697258/facebook-graph-api-oauth-token)

> I ran into the exact same problem but
>   it turned out the issue is not the
>   encoding of the redirect_uri
>   parameter, or that I had a trailing
>   slash or question mark it's simply
>   that I passed in two different
>   redirect urls (had not read the
>   specification at that time).
>
> The redirect_uri is only used as a
>   redirect once (the first time) to
>   redirect back to the relying party
>   with the "code" token. The 2nd time,
>   the redirect_uri is passed back to the
>   auth server but this time it's not
>   used as you'd expect (to redirect)
>   rather it's used by the authentication
>   server to verify the code. The server
>   responds with the access_token.
>
> You'll notice facebook documentation
>   (which is terrible) says fetch
>   "Exchange it for an access token by
>   fetching ....
>   "
>
> In summary, I didn't have to encode or
>   do anything special to the Uri, just
>   pass in the same redirect_uri twice,
>   and fetch the 2nd page to get the
>   access_token inside.

I didn't copy my original code correctly and the redirect uri I was passing to get the code was different than the uri I was passing to get the access token.  Facebook's API documentation is terrible :(

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem/error but finally found a different solution (by comparing my Dev app settings which was working) to my prod app settings (which was generating this error).

I went to the advanced settings page for my app in the Facebook Developer app:
https://developers.facebook.com/apps/YourAppID/advanced

Then I found the "Encrypted Access Token:" setting and turn it to "Enabled."