# How to programmatically publish to a facebook feed for a liked webpage?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to get this to work: https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/465/

**Step 1:** I'm getting an access token:

https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?type=client_cred&client_id=myAppIdclient_secret=myAppSecret

**Step 2:** I'm posting via curl

```
curl -F 'access_token=myAccessToken'  -F 'message=Hello World!'  -F 'id=http://example.com'  https://graph.facebook.com/feed
```

Where myUrl is say http://example.com

I am getting this error, does not resolve to a valid user ID:

```
{"error":{"message":"(#100) http:\/\/example does not resolve to a valid user ID","type":"OAuthException","code":100}}
```

**Step 3:** If I first post my url to the linter, and get its ID:

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Fexample.com

https://graph.facebook.com/10150096126766188

```
curl -F 'access_token=myAccessToken'  -F 'message=Hello World!'  -F 'id=10150096126766188'  https://graph.facebook.com/feed
```

Then I get 'The user hasn't authorized the application to perform this action' error:

```
{"error":{"message":"(#200) The user hasn't authorized the application to perform this action","type":"OAuthException","code":200}}
```

Comment: I got this working on two of my websites, but now I'm stuck again trying to get this to work on a new website :(

Answer (score 0):

From the [Facebook Graph API docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/):

```
Most write operations require extended permissions[1] for the active user.
See the authentication guide[2] for details on how you can request extended
permissions from the user during the authentication step.
```

1 https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/permissions

2 https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/

Comment: Hey Fraser.  Am I missing something - there is no active user here.

Comment: I'm wishing Stackoverflow would join the 21st century and notify people of answers and comments :)

Comment: I'm assuming you are leaving out your access token on purpose in the example above?

Comment: yep.  I can share it privately if you want.

Answer (score 0):

Going by the blog post this is done via an app, for this to work the app needs the extended permissions 'publish_actions' and 'publish_stream' in order to make posts/comments/likes/links

Comment: That sounds promising, any idea how I can give my app those permissions?

Comment: This page:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/permissions/#extended_perms

goes into more detail with regards extended permissions.

You can test via : https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer
and manually putting in the token when you have ticked the appropriate boxes

Comment: I think this might be confusing two different topics... Are you thinking that a facebook app needs permissions to publish to its own pages?